# WordPress have_pots() returning 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I have  a WordPress site, containing nearly 500 posts, of which many are imported from other site. But  shows only '1'.
How can I get the actual no: of posts?

Comment: check the following link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

Comment: its not working for me, do I need to add ay reference, since I've exported those posts.?

Comment: you want to count posts only right?? please add any code how you try to do?

Comment: `echo wp_count_posts()`...

Comment: echo wp_count_posts(); is returning blank, where as echo wp_count_posts()->publish; returns the actual no: of published posts.. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Share the code you have tried

Comment: `wp_count_posts()` returns an object which cannot be echoed as is, you should use the properties (e.g. `publish`) to get the number of posts with the wanted post status.

Comment: In Admin side, can you see your imported posts?

Comment: Yes i can see all posts

Comment: What i need is to get loop through posts and display in the format, TITLE EXCERPT DATE TAGS CATEGORIES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

$total_posts = wp_count_posts(); /* Returns the number of posts */

echo $total_posts->publish;      /* Prints the number of published posts */

EDIT:

Based on our conversations below, here's the answer you were looking for:

```
$articles = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); 

while ($articles->have_posts()): $articles->the_post(); 
    echo the_title; 
    echo the_excerpt; 
    echo the_tags; 
    echo the_date;      
    echo the_category(); 
endwhile;
```

Comment: Please read my comment, wp_count_psots returning blank
wp_count_posts()->publish is working properly

Comment: Per the documentation, wp_count_posts returns an object rather than just a count. That's why you need to use the publish property to get the count you're looking for. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

Comment: What i need is to get loop through posts and display in the format, 
TITLE
EXCERPT
DATE
TAGS 
CATEGORIES

Comment: That's a little different: Try this:

Comment: $articles = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post'));
        while ($articles->have_posts()): $articles->the_post();
            echo the_title;
            echo the_excerpt;
            echo the_tags;
            echo the_date;
           echo the_category();
        endwhile;

Comment: <?php  
     $articles = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post')); ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (($articles->have_posts()) : $articles->the_post();    
     
     echo the_title; 
     echo the_excerpt;
     echo the_tags; 
     echo the_date; 
     echo the_category(); ?>
    

                    <?php endwhile; ?>


is this what you said?

Comment: Terry, i am not getting all my posts, only 10 posts are seen.
next and previous tags are present, but not visible, since only 10 posts are taken

Comment: Try setting posts_per_page to -1 in the WP_Query logic. In other words, the first line should look like this: $articles = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' = -1));

Comment: I added the solution above. Please let me know if it helped or if you have any questions about it

Comment: can anyone please help me to solve this problem. On exporting posts, the <p> tags missing and alignment issues arise, how can i solve?

Answer (score 1):

`have_posts()` is used for a single post query. `have_posts()` returns either `1` (for "true) or `0` (for "false"), depending on whether the `WP_Query` object has any posts available.

To get the actual post count of a single `WP_Query` object, use

```
$post_count = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

To get the post count of all posts inside your WordPress installation, you can use

```
$all_posts = wp_count_posts();
$published = $all_posts->publish;
```

EDIT:

To make a new query that contains each and every published post inside WordPress:

```
$full_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'nopaging' => 1, // Remove if you want pagination.
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // -1 sets no pagination, set to a number of posts per page you wish to have.
));

if ($full_query->have_posts()) {
    ... normal WP loop here ...
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display a list of all the posts available in your WordPress installation?

Comment: What i need is to get loop through posts and display in the format, TITLE EXCERPT DATE TAGS CATEGORIES

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example of fetching all WP posts.